# Div Not Creating Height

Tags: css, html, height

I have a `div` that contains an `h2` and three `div`'s, but it is not creating height. I don't recall having this issue before. But basically, the three containing `div`'s need to be flexible in height, so I can't give the container `div` a set height. Since it isn't creating height, my footer floats on top of the `div`. If you hover over the "recent" `div` in firebug or inspector, you'll notice the height of the `div` only extends the height and margin of the `h2`. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Here's the fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/s5p49/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three inner divs are set to `float: left`, and therefore do not affect the height of their parent. You need to clear them. There are various ways to do this; one is to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent.

```
#recent {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 824px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

There are various other methods out there as well, some better than others. I would encourage you to read http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, specifically the part *Techniques for Clearing Floats*.